# How do I remove the program status that output to txt?

Tags: java, java-io, status

I got a txt with many sentences .

I m using an external library called anticAnalysis-master.

I read that txt and translate every sentences into code (1/0/-1) using `analysis.parse(line).getCode()`. Finally it would output into another .txt.

Just like the picture below ,it generates the program status in the output console .The red lines in output console are generated automatically

However ,it prints out the program status into the txt too.

Therefore, How do I get rid of that line of program status from the txt?(picture 2)

```
final int[] score = {
    0
};
try (Stream < String > stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("D:\\out.txt")).sequential()) { //retrieve txt file
    File file = new File("D:\\analysis.txt"); //output file
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
    System.setOut(ps);
    final Analysis analysis = new Analysis();
    stream.forEach(line - > {


                System.out.println("Code: " + analysis.parse(line).getCode()); //translate every lines into code

                score[0] = score[0] + analysis.parse(line).getCode(); //add up the total score 
            }

            System.out.println("score=" + score[0]); //print out the total score
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't redirect standard output. Instead, just print to your new file.

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
final Analysis analysis = new Analysis();
stream.forEach(line - > {
    ps.println("Code: " + analysis.parse(line).getCode()); 
    score[0] = score[0] + analysis.parse(line).getCode(); 
}
```

Comment: this work. Can you add explanation on wt are the difference b/w both method

Comment: Also , is it able to blind the red status on the output console ?

Comment: By default Java has a PrintStream referred to as StandardOut. `System.out.println()` outputs to StandardOut. 

In this solution, instead of printing to StandardOut, you are printing to your separate File Output PrintStream.

Comment: is it able to blind the red status on the output console ?

Comment: Not directly. You might be able to accomplish that by redirecting StandardOut to not write to the Console. Then nothing would be written to the Console. If you have a more advanced scenario then create a new Stack Overflow Question with more details, and I will post a detailed answer.